# Trying to figure out available resources on MSP430 LaunchPad

Tags: serial, mosfet, rs232, msp430

I'm just starting to mess with the MSP430 and have some simple apps working fine.  However, now I want to use it with an LCD and am trying to determine if I'm short on I/O.  For sure, I'll need to use the 4-bit interface, and I also need 3 outputs for E, RW, and RS.  On top of that, I need to talk to my computer over RS232, but **not** via the built-in COM port-over-USB.

I've been looking over the documentation and can't figure out which lines the onboard FET is using.  The situation I'm in is, I'd like to debug my application, but then need the FET.  If the FET uses the TX/RX lines, then I can't test my serial code.

So the questions I have are:

1. What's the best documentation to look at to figure out the answer to my question?  I've been Googling and reading the [MSP430x2xx Family User's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf).
2. Do people typically break up applications on the MSP430 into more logical groups to get around I/O shortages, and then combine at the end and hope for the best?  This is the approach I would typically use.  For example, I could use a different set of lines for TX/RX to test the software serial feature in one application, then test the LCD w/o serial support in another application.  Then at the end, I could reassign the TX/RX lines and combine the features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I'm offering what I think is another potential answer to my question.

First, I'm not sure why I had such a hard time finding the correct datasheet initially, but the MSP430G2231 datasheet is [here](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2231.pdf).

[image]

From this datasheet, page 6 clearly lists the functions of each pin.  It turns out that while XIN and XOUT are the default functions for pins 13 and 12, respectively, they can also be configured as GPIO.  Sweet!

So TX and RX can be used for the software serial UART, where sample code is found [here](http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Components-PostAttachments/00-00-28-69-22/msp430g2xx1_5F00_ta_5F00_uart9600.c).  I can bitbang the 4 bit bus on the LCD using P1.4,P1.5,P1.6, and P1.7, which are conveniently contiguous.  E, RS, and RW can be controlled by P1.3, P2.6, and P2.7.  I even end up with an extra I/O, so I can just keep P1.0 connected to the LaunchPad's LED for extra debugging info!

I'd be interested to hear some comments about this.

EDIT -- on another note, it looks like the TEST and RST pins are used for Spy-Bi-Wire.  Isn't that what TI uses on the LaunchPad for communication with the FET?

Answer (score 5):

One reason why the Launchpad is so cheap is because the chip it uses is a very low-end device, which is missing many useful peripherals such as a UART. You will find things much easier if you use one of the other, more capable, devices You will need a FET, of course, but they aren't all that expensive, and it is a very useful tool.

Pins 16 and 17 on the target device are used for debugging. It might be possible to use them in your application if they are isolated with resistors, Microchip recommends that solution for debugging their devices when the ICSP pins are in use.

Most people build software like that starting from a simple application using one peripheral, and then add the additional functionality to the same program. Combining programs can cause problems.

A useful resource for MSP430 development is [this](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/msp430/) Yahoo MSP430 group.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at the 20 pin devices.  But for now, I guess it wouldn't hurt to just tackle the LCD and use the built-in COM port via the FET.

Answer (score 1):

If you need some extra slow IO, you can add some 74HC595 or 2 which can give you some 8-16 extra IO lines for 2 lines on uC(1 line with tricks). It will cost you some 0.2$ each.

Comment: hey that's a good idea, too!  thanks.  I'm going to see what I can squeeze out of this device first and then will look at the other options.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the newer 20pin Pdip or favorite package 
msp430G23xx or msp430g24xx
They have expanded ports 2x 8bit ports = 16outputs 
more timers and built in hardware UART

but for your current conundrum, You can use the tx and rx on the FET- just disconnect the jumpers and connect the pins to your level converter(max232) You do not need the rx tx to program it from my experience.

second question, is yes i break it up into smaller chunks and once i know all my code works i start putting it all together. so far it works great for smaller projects for me.

Comment: http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/msp430g2332.html

Comment: thanks for the tips on the newer parts.  I was originally going to say that I'd like to confirm that I'm outside of the capabilities of the smaller chip, but it might also be nice to have a hardware UART.  Decisions, decisions...

Comment: Hmm... looks to me like none of the MSP430G chips have a UART.  See http://focus.ti.com/en/multimedia/flash/selection_tools/mcu/mcu.html.  What's the difference between MSP430C/F/G?  Looks like the F and C types have UARTs available, but I don't think they are compatible with LaunchPad since they don't even come in a DIP package.

Comment: all msp430s with 2 wire SBW (spy by wire) are compatible with the launchpad, I have successfully used f2013, f2011 in projects. I know some of the bigger chips you have to have the FET tool or come they come with a bootloader. I know G line chips are value line chips, F I think is just there standard line, and C I couldn't find any info on. I will dig up some more info in a bit.

Comment: @jsolarski thanks!  Yeah, google failed me when I was trying to figure out the difference between the letter codes... :)

Comment: @jsolarski so are you proposing that I try one of the other chips with SBW in a non PDIP package, and just fly wires or get an adapter board?  I guess I just have to make sure that the TEST and RST lines are on the right pins...

Comment: Its up to you on your package choice, but all i am saying is you have options. From what i have found, G line chips will have uart built in on future chips. As of right now start testing out your code and order msp430g2x52 or comparable chip http://focus.ti.com/mcu/docs/quickdatasheets.tsp?familyId=1937 if you need the extra IO and launchpad compatible.

Comment: FYI a another community that can help http://www.43oh.com/

Comment: @jsolarski Thanks!  43oh has come up quite a bit in my searches and it looks like a great resource.

Comment: From the mspgcc doc, the letters int the part number refer to the kind of ROM used by the device (http://mspgcc.sourceforge.net/manual/x675.html)